# anonymous object, initialize object, static , final static , for improve performance?

Tags: java, android, object, anonymous

In my android application `I just want development tips`,

If i want to just set **value/image only one time at onCreate()**. 

**1 way**) Which is best way, by ***initialize object***. 

Or
**2 way**) using ***anonymous object***.

`((TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView_footer_left)).setText("Text added at run time");`

Above case with different condition, now i want to access textview/imageview 2 or 3 times then  which way is better 1st way or 2nd way.

***Static:***
in which cash we should use `static` keyword?

***final static:***
in which cash we should use `final static` keyword?

My main agenda is.

**i want to write code which is more robust, faster and less memory consumption**.

let me also help in GC behavior.

Comment: @lenabru Thanks for your answer and please give more tips for development so i can develop powerful app with good performance.

Comment: i will gladly help you, however the tips you request, are specific per app requirements ;), so if you have any questions feel free to ask me

Answer (score 3):

findViewById is a recursive costly operation. You want to limit these calls to the minimum.
So if you want to use the object more than once, keep a reference to it

Comment: Also, see the ViewHolder pattern: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder

Comment: **Avoid Creating Unnecessary Objects** 
Object creation is never free. A generational garbage collector with per-thread allocation pools for temporary objects can make allocation cheaper, but allocating memory is always more expensive than not allocating memory.

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation

Comment: please explain me i really very much confuse.

Comment: @BhaveshJethani What else is there to explain? We won't do it better by just rephrasing the documentation. This is beyond the scope of comments on SOF.

Comment: @Blacklight As per my understanding, Android document is talking us to  avoid unnecessary obj. if i want to use 2 3 times should i have to create reference of the object?

Answer (score 0):

**i want to write code which is more robust, faster and less memory consumption.**

If you are accessing more that once, initilize by `static final`

`final Textview mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);`

[Performance Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal)

Comment: it is never good to keep **static** references to views. They prevent activity from being released when he's done with it

Comment: I don't think that's going to work for two reasons: 1) `findViewById` isn't `static` and 2) your view hasn't been inflated at that point so it'll return `null`.

Comment: @JanVandenbosch Nope, It doesn't return null you can try it.

Comment: @LenaBru oh, I did not know that, I have been using this way as suggested in [android Performance Tips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#UseFinal) Thanks for the info, but I will not accept it, unless you can show me a proof.

Comment: @VenomVendor You cannot compare primitive data types in static final constants to views (with a lifecycle)! You are interpreting the documentation incorrectly.

Comment: @VenomVendor: it doesn't even compile because of the `static` keyword and if I remove it, `findViewById` throws a NullPointerException. It doesn't work.

Comment: @JanVandenbosch Oops, yeah, I have used only `final` & not `static` to views. Just checked my code & made an edit.